# Show the existence of two numbers.

Tags: real-analysis

$f$ is continuous on $[0,n]$ (where $n\in\mathbb{N}$) and $f(0)=f(n)$.
 Prove that there
$$\exists a,b\in[0,n]$$
so that $b-a=1$ and $f(b)=f(a)$.

I believe this is related to the Universal chord theorem, but I haven't used that before and so don't know the logic behind it. How should I prove the last two equations?

Comment: $ n\geq 1 \text{}$ ?

Comment: Yes, I have fixed my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $g:[0,n-1]\to \mathbb R, x\mapsto f(x+1)-f(x)$ and suppose for the sake of contradiction that $g$ is never $0$. Since $g$ is continuous, we may assume WLOG that $g>0$. Then $0<g(0)=f(1)-f(0)$ and $0<g(n-1)=f(n)-f(n-1)$, hence $f(1)>f(0)$ and $f(0)>f(n-1)$.

But $f(n-1)-f(1)=\sum_{k=1}^{n-2} (f(k+1)-f(k))>0$, thus $f(n-1)>f(1)>f(0)$, a contradiction.

Comment: How is $g$ defined? $g(x)=f(x+1)-f(x)$?

Comment: @pls_halp yes, sorry for mistyping this

Comment: Where did $f(0)>f(n−1)$ come from?

Comment: @pls_halp I derived $f(n)>f(n-1)$ and then used $f(n)=f(0)$.

Answer (score 1):

If $n=1$ you are done. Otherwise define 
$$g(x)=f(x)-f(x+1).$$

Note that 
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} g(k) = f(0)-f(n)=0.$$

Hence, $g(k)=0$ for all $0\le k\le n$ (and you're done) or there exists $0\le k_1$,$k_2\le n$ such that
$$g(k_1) <0<g(k_2).$$
The intermediate value theorem then finishes this off.

Hope this helps!

Comment: that's a neat argument !